# django web-project with category

Tags: django

in my blog-project with django,i want to have a page such as category.html to show all the categories ,and when i clicked the link of a category ,it shows the artical of the category,just like this: `http:xxx/category` show all the categories i have ,and `http:xxx/category/django` show all the artical of django

how to do ?

```
class CategoryView(ListView):
    template_name = "index.html"
    context_object_name = "article_list"

    def get_queryset(self):
        article_list = Post.objects.filter(category=self.kwargs['id'])
        return article_list

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        kwargs['category_list'] = Category.objects.all().order_by('cate_name')
        return super(CategoryView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can make another app called categories, then you can show all relative to them, like create, edit, delete categories, also you can list all categories you have, thats is up to you,

in the url file you have to map the route for example:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [

    #rutas for category app 
    url(r'^$', views.list , name="input_list" ),

    url(r'^add/$', views.add, name="input_add" ),

    url(r'^edit/(?P<in_id>[0-9]+)$', views.input_update , name="input_update" ),

]
```

the your view file will be something like:

```
def list( request ):

    cat_list = Category.objects.all()

    return render(request, 'category/category_list.html',{ 'cat_list': cat_list } )
```

.
.
.
an so on for the other sections of category app

of course before thar you have to map the url from your project to your app and have all the files in the template directory ( all html files you need )